# How can I print the filename of a graphics file in pdf

Tags: graphics

I would like to print the true filename of a graphics file, such as example.jpg, close to the position where the figure actually appears in the pdf file?

Comment: Dear closing voters: I think you should at least have the kindness of explaining in a comment the reasons for voting to close so quickly. If it seems "unclear" to you, leave a comment and give time for the OP to clarify or elaborate!

Answer (score 7):

You can define a command for this, such as

```
\newcommand\Includegraphics[2][scale=1]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}\par\nobreak\texttt{#2}}
```

to typeset the file name below the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\Includegraphics[2][scale=1]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}\par\nobreak\texttt{#2}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\Includegraphics[width=4cm]{ctanlion.png}

\noindent
\Includegraphics[width=4cm]{mushrooms.jpg}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, using `\marginnote` to typeset the name as a marginal note:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand\Includegraphics[2][]{%
  \marginnote{\fbox{\texttt{#2}}}[-\baselineskip]\adjustbox{valign=c}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\Includegraphics[width=4cm]{ctanlion.png}

\noindent
\Includegraphics[width=4cm]{mushrooms.jpg}

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Comment: Thank you so much. A friend of mine came up with another similar solution                                                    \newcommand{\saveinclude}{}
\let\saveinclude\includegraphics
\newcommand{\filename}[1]{\tiny\ttfamily{\detokenize{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\saveinclude[#1]{#2}\marginnote{\filename{#2}}}

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine came up with another similar solution

```
%%for the preamble

\newcommand{\saveinclude}{} 
\let\saveinclude\includegraphics
\newcommand{\filename}[1]{\tiny\ttfamily{\detokenize{#1}}} 
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\saveinclude[#1]{#2}\marginnote{\filename{#‌​2}}}

%%in the text just use \includegraphics[]{}
```

Answer (score 1):

We redefine `\includegraphics` to output the name of the included graphics file.

Note that the code also works for file names given **without** extension. The same list of filename extensions as used by the `graphicx` package is searched for a matching file:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\def\getfilename#1{%
  \begingroup%
  \IfFileExists{#1}{\texttt{#1}}{%
    \let\firstmatch\undefined%
    \filename@parse{#1}\edef\curbase{\filename@area\filename@base}%
    \@for\tempa:=\Gin@extensions\do{%
      \edef\curfile{{\curbase\tempa}}%
      \ifdefined\firstmatch\else%
        \expandafter\IfFileExists\curfile{\expandafter\texttt\curfile\def\firstmatch{}}{}%
      \fi%  
    }%
  }%
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatletter

\let\igraphicsorig\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{\vtop{%
  \hbox{\igraphicsorig[#1]{#2}}%
  \hbox{\getfilename{#2}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
%includes ctanlion.png, if found first
\verb+\includegraphics[width=4cm]{ctanlion}+:\\
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{ctanlion}

\vspace{2cm}

\noindent%
\verb+\includegraphics[width=4cm]{ctanlion.eps}+:\\
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{ctanlion.eps}
\end{document}
```