# Easiest way to reorganize complex .tex document that inputs / includes multiple tex files

Tags: multiple-files, organisation

**Issue description**

I have a big document that includes a few .tex files that includes (or rather `\input`) another set of *.tex* files stored in different folders.

I will need to re-organize structure of my document: move some sections and subsections as well as creating new one.

**Sample file structure**

For example, in *main.tex* I have following line

```
\input{./tekst/Pomiary.tex}
```

and in Pomiary.tex I have:

```
\chapter{Metody pomiarowe}

\input{./tekst/pomiary/PomNaziemne.tex}
```

and in *PomNaziemne.tex* I include another set of files

---

**Question**

I wonder if there are any dedicated tools for reorganizing complex LaTeX document?

If not, are there any editors that allows me to click on particular part of the PDF (document Preview) and get a hint where this part is (in which file it exists and how it was included?).

In [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com) when I click on particular part of PDF, I'm moved to appropriate line in .tex file, but to locate file which I'm editing, I need to manually expand list of folders and look for file name that is bold.

Comment: please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23063/extended-draft-mode-which-includes-source-information-for-manual-print-out-to-so and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359143/display-print-input-filename-at-top-of-each-page-in-draft-mode