# Include filename in a nested document

Tags: input, subfiles, currfile

I have a large project split in multiple files. I'd like to get each subfile name in the pdf to monitor my document.

From different posts on this forum I understand `Currfile` package could help, by using `\currfilename`.
From [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261276/have-input-print-the-filename), I get that it would be far too manual to implement, since I have probably 100 subfiles. It would be far too long to add `\currfilename` to every one of them.

Is there a clever way to input the file name of the subfile that in being `\input` in `Main.tex` without having to type it for each subfile ? In other words, is there a way to include `\currfilename` right after `\input` calls the subfile ?

```
\begin{filecontents}{File1.tex}
\currfilename
\lipsum
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{File2.tex}
\currfilename
\lipsum
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{File3.tex}
\currfilename
\lipsum
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{File4.tex}
\currfilename
\lipsum
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\input{File1.tex}
\input{File2.tex}
\input{File3.tex}
\input{File4.tex}


\end{document}
```

Comment: if you did not have `\currfilename` in the file isn't the required output just `File1.tex \input{File1.tex} File2.tex \input{File2.tex}` ?

Comment: Forgive my English David. I wish I had know about '\currfilename' before I wrote the 100 (actually more) subfiles. In MWE it was easy to implement the result I wanted. How could I avoid the burden of rewriting '\currfilename' in every single subfile ?

Comment: The mwe would if it had over 100 similar {filecontents} be a simple internal find and replace on a key phrase such as the \begin{itemize} replace with \currfilename \begin{itemize}
. However I suspect in reality your file is nothing like the mwe structure (is it ?) so I then have to query could you not do a find and replace in each of the real \inputs. to give an accurate answer requires knowing it is a true reflection of the question.

Comment: @KJO I thought the purpose of MWE was actually to show a simplified version of my problem ? My problem is I have many subfiles. They'll all be '\input{Subfile1},...,\input{Subfile100}' from my main.tex. I am just trying to know if there is a way to force '\input' to include the file name I am inputing right before it parse the text of this file.

Comment: But why do you need to do that at all, is it not just the same as putting the text of the filename before the input. if you go `foobar \input{foobar}` then the final pdf will have the filename in the output

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "putting the text of the filename before the input" you mean manually ? Because that's what I try to avoid. Terminally, I'd love to have the option to switch on or off the option to display the filename in the output pdf. Kinda  working version vs final version.

Comment: just use your editor to change the `\input` to `\myinput` then `\newcommand\myinput[1]{#1\input{#1}}` when you want the name printed or `\newcommand\myinput[1]{\input{#1}}` when you do not

Comment: Thank you David. Fast and simple enough for my small level. Merci ! But tell me if I am wrong. I'll lose the ability (as in Texmaker for intance) to click on the file name on the structure part since '\input' i not recogized ? (I must ask silly questions but I am a beginner)

Answer (score 1):

You linked to the answer but just to be clear try this
in the editor cautiously find and replace \input{ with \inputf{

As queried this will affect the editors ability to jump to from subfiles the safest way to handle that would be to simply prepend all subfiles with the  line \currfilename and I give two more risky alternative solutions below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%\usepackage{currfile} % not required
\usepackage{lipsum} % for demonstration each file contains \lipsum[1]

\newcommand\inputf[1]{\texttt{#1} \par\nobreak\input{#1}} % filename before
%\newcommand\inputf[1]{\input{#1}} % Per David's comment, uncomment this line and comment the line above to "resume normal service"

\begin{document}

\inputf{File1.tex}

\inputf{File2.tex}

\inputf{File3.tex}

\inputf{File4.tex}
\end{document}
```

We could stick with the original request to add \currfile to all \inputs (thus retaining the natural workflow. so the main.tex stays the same with one added line)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{currfile} %required for modified inputs
\usepackage{lipsum}  %for demo only

\begin{document}
\input{file1.tex} % note it is this name that the file has (lowercase file)
\input{File2.tex} % note in the screenshot this is the name that \input \currfilename uses, however the real file name is lowercase file..
\input{File3.tex}
\input{File4.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image]

each of the tex files is prepended with a header stored in a file say **currfile.txt** containing

```
\texttt \currfilename \par
```

On windows this can be easily processed to the start of each txt file by using a **AddCurrfile.cmd** file in the same directory. (you run this at your own risk I have included a safety backup on first line but always test on a copy folder.)

```
for %%f in (file???.tex) do ren %%f %%~nf.bak
for %%f in (file???.bak) do copy currfile.txt/B+%%f/B %%~nf.tex/B
```

To revert the tex files to previous behaviour you could script the removal/rename *HOWEVER* I did say **keep a backup folder without the changes** did I not ?

**Finally probably the solution you were looking** for but its somewhat risky since it modifies a major command thus may impact other \inputs and I thus cannot control how you apply it.

Add this to your preamble and remove/comment out when not required.

```
% changing the syntax of a major command is not a good approach, so better to consider sticking with one of the two above solutions:
\makeatletter
\let\latex@input\input
\newcommand\current@input[1]{\texttt{#1} \par\nobreak\latex@input{#1}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\input\current@input}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
```